# How to check if the string is valid Url path format

Tags: android, validation, url

Understands that using Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches() will able to validate if that string is a valid url, however it will required in a full format which contain https: / .com.

In my case, i want to validate if the json return a string in correct format for path e.g /images/slider/my/myImage.jpg; which does not contain https or any. How can i do this?

What i want to do is something like:

```
if(ImageUrl equal "/images/slider/my/myImage.jpg" FORMAT) {
     //Do something here
} else //ImageUrl = myImage.jpg {
    //Add "/images/slider/my/" infront of the text
}
```

P.s: My image link will be like www.abc.com/images/slider/my/myImage.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Use URLUtil to validate the URL as below.

```
 URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

It will return True if URL is valid and false if URL is invalid.

Another way is given below.

```
public static boolean checkURL(CharSequence input) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(input)) {
        return false;
    }
    Pattern URL_PATTERN = Patterns.WEB_URL;
    boolean isURL = URL_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches();
    if (!isURL) {
        String urlString = input + "";
        if (URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(urlString)) {
            try {
                new URL(urlString);
                isURL = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return isURL;
}
```

[This link will explain how you can check the url is available or not.](https://androidprogramz.blogspot.com/2012/07/check-url-is-available-or-not.html)

For more about URLS please visit [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil)

Please have a try

Comment: Both method still return false for "/images/slider/my/myImage.jpg". Which means i will need to add Http:// infont for validate

Comment: Yes . without http it is not a valid url

Comment: how could i do if i want to check if the image url path is reachable? I means instead of checking the string only i want to test if the url can run